# html agility pack text inside in li

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am getting data inside <'li> tag like this:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var list = new List<string>(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")
                                            .Select(li => li.InnerText));
```

but if li has another tag inside like `<em>` that been ignored.
How can I keep everything inside in `<li>` without using InnerHtml?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `OuterHtml`.
Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

> The **outerHTML** attribute of the Element DOM interface gets the
> serialized HTML fragment describing **the element including its
> descendants**. It can also be set to replace the element with nodes
> parsed from the given string.
>
> To only obtain the HTML representation of the **contents of an element**,
> or to replace the contents of an element, use the **innerHTML** property
> instead.

```
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(@"
<ul>
    <li>
        <em>item 1</em>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>item</span> <em>2</em> <br/>
    </li>
</ul>
            ");

            var ul = doc.DocumentNode.Element("ul");
            var lis = ul.Elements("li");
            foreach(var li in lis)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------------- inner html -------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(li.InnerText); //prints "Item N" (content only)
                Console.WriteLine("----------------- outer html -------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(li.OuterHtml); //prints <li> + all descending tags + </li>
            }
```